# Как сделать скролл не страницы, а модального окна?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Заказчик жалуется что у него модальное окно выглядит вот так[image: вот так]

[делаю окно модалки вот для этого сайта №1](http://mytrueblog.site/place_relax/reservation.php#)

[есть почти такой же сайт в нем заказчик говорит что у него мдальное окно выглядит нормально №2](https://gornaya-derevnya.ru/prices/)

в общем я решил переделать скролл(как сделано в сайте№2) чтобы при открывании модалки у body появлялось overflow-y: hidden -отключался скролл
а у модального окна он появлялся свой скролл overflow-y: auto, как сделано в сайте №2.
но не работает почему-то

```
$(function(){
  function showModal(id){
    $(document.body).addClass('modal_hidden');
    $(id).addClass('modal_active');
    console.log(id);
  }
  function hideModals(){
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal_hidden');
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal_active');
  }

  $(".button_modal").on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    showModal('#modal');
 });

  $(document).on('click', function(e){
    if (!(
    ($(e.target).parents('.modal-block').length)
    ||  ($(e.target).hasClass('modal-block'))
    ||  ($(e.target).hasClass('button_modal')))
    ) {
      hideModals();
    }
  });

});
```

мне кажется проблема связана с тем что modal_active-hidden всегда находится на body, хотя должен появляться только при нажатии на модальное окно

```
.modal
  position: fixed
  display: none
  left: 0
  top: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  background-color: rgba(#000, 0.7)
  +reg
  z-index: 2
  overflow-x: hidden
  overflow-y: auto
  &_active
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    &-hidden
      overflow-y: hidden
```

Comment: поставьте высоту модалке и скролл, к примеру, `height: 90vh; overflow: auto`, если модалка вмещается в экран нормально, то скрола не будет

Comment: ставлю 90vh это решает проблему с уведением модалки в потолок, но проблема возникает с низу, блока недостаточна для содержимого ![вот тут видно](https://ibb.co/JHmXxSn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант

```css
body.overflow {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.modal_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1001;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body class="overflow">
  Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
  text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
  text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
  text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
  text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
  text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>
  <div class="modal_wrap">
    <div class="modal"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Проблему почти удалось решить, скролл от body убрал, скролл для модалки поставил, но есть проблема, при уменьшении высоты экрана модальное окно уплывает вверх в небытие,а скрол работает только в низ, можете подсказать как с этим быть?

Comment: Можете где-то эту проблему показать?

Comment: ![тут видно](https://ibb.co/30Gzb4G) как блок уводит вверх

Comment: В указанном мной варианте такой проблемы нет, можете создать чистый проект и на нем проверить. Затем заменить ваши стили на этот вариант. Если у вас проблемы со скроллом то где в css есть стили которые что-то еще поверх добавляют и ломают отображение. Что бы увидеть в чем проблема нужно смотреть на рабочий проект, только так